# Highlighting the current Step in a multi step form page

Tags: asp.net

i am using a simple form page with 4 steps in it i am not using any wizard control for this i want to highlight the current step what i have to do for achieving this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (WhateverPanel.Visible == true) {
    StepLabel.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.WhateverYouWant;
}
```

Or for labels it might be

```
StepLabel.Styles.BackColor = ...
```

I have to get to work or I'd check. Regardless, put that in the Page_Load and you should be gravy.

Comment: can you suggest me some site in which something like this is there

Comment: None off the top of my head. If you're using panels for something like this you should really consider looking into a MultiView.

Comment: ya that's all right for designing purpose i want to have a look to other site something like
step1>>step2>>step3

Comment: Here's something you might find interesting: http://css-tricks.com/anythingslider-jquery-plugin/. Found it browsing earlier and thought of this thread.